# How to set a queried field in a subreport in Visual Studio 2012 Reporting Services equal to the same key field in the main report?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I currently have account data in the main report within a table from the general ledger data and I would like to include data from the pending report in a table below (which I believe is achieved through the sub report but I only want to show an account number that is equal to the main general ledger report.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the sub-report, click on it, and select the "Parameters" property.

This will open a dialog that will let you map the parameters of the sub-report to the values available in the main report.